# Not able to open links from any Office 2007/2010

Tags: outlook-2010, outlook-2007

When clicking on a link in word or outlook two users on the domain get this message.

**Error**:This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator.

It appears that everyone has the group policy applied properly.

Any info will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it!

I did a search for the error message and it took me to a Microsoft support page.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310049

I downloaded Microsoft's "Fix this problem"
Microsoft Fix it 50388

Well I hope this helps someone else.